# Identify Support / Resistance levels & Trend-lines

Tags: java, python, python-3.x, technical-indicator

I don't need a code just the logic on how to do this.
[Example of S/R levels and a trendline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ntW7.png)

I know s/r levels differ from one person to another so I have attached a graph to show what criteria I use to consider a support/resistance level or a trend line.

- S/R level has to have more than 2 touches if there are more than over fits this criterion then the one with most touchdowns is the valid one, same for resistance.
- A trend line has to have 3 touches in order to be valid.

All lines have a margin error since these lines can get extended. and of course, once a support line is broken it turns into resistance.

I tried taking an array of min values then see if other bars fall within a certain range of these values but it wasn't accurate enough!

Answer (score 1):

Below is something for you to start with. Emphasis on the 'start' because it doesn't directly answer your questions.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

Simulate data.

```
np.random.seed(42)
mu = 0.03
ret = mu+np.random.randn(500)
price = 1+np.cumsum(ret)
```

Look for `support` by first, removing noise from signal with moving average.  Offset by `support` value, then look for locations where offset value is at zero, which would be the locations touching the `support line`.

```
def get_support_line(df,days=100):
    df['price_ma']=df['price'].rolling(5).mean()
    df = df.dropna()
    supports={}

    for x in np.arange(0,len(df)-days,10):
        price_tmp = df.iloc[x:x+days]['price_ma'].values
        # offset signal by support value, loc crossing 0 will be support.
        support_val = price_tmp[-1]
        norm = price_tmp-support_val
        lim = 0.05 # hack to find intersect with support line with tolerance
        signal = np.logical_and(norm<lim,norm>-1*lim).astype(np.int)
        inds = np.where(np.diff(signal)>0)[0]
        if np.sum(signal)>3:
            supports[x+days]={
                'x':inds+x,
                'y':support_val*np.ones(inds.shape)
            }
    return df, supports

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['price']=price
df, supports = get_support_line(df)
```

Plot to verify logic. You now should start tweaking the free parameters and also the logic to your "liking".

```
df.plot(figsize=(10,5))
for k,v in supports.items():
    print('support identified at days prior index',k,'value: {:1.2f}'.format(v['y'][0]),'touch inds:',v['x'])
    plt.plot([v['x'][0],v['x'][-1]],[v['y'][0],v['y'][-1]],color='red')
plt.grid(True)
```

[image]

I don't buy technical analysis, but I think this is an interesting problem, implementation wise! There should be lots of libraries out there. so please be sure to do a google search, and come back and share your solutions and findings.

Comment: thanks a lot, but unfortunately using a moving average to filter and help to detect S/R levels isn't a good idea and results in very inaccurate lines!.